# how class array work(c++)? Does it get a memory while declaration?

Tags: c++

Program quote:(stephen prata,c++ primer plus sixth edition, 4.24)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...

using namespace std;

double a1[4] = {1.2, 2.4, 3.6, 4.8};
vector<double> a2(4);
a2[0] = 1.0/3.0;
a2[1] = 1.0/5.0;
a2[2] = 1.0/7.0;
a2[3] = 1.0/9.0;

array<double, 4> a3 = {3.14, 2.72, 1.62, 1.41};
array<double, 4> a4;
a4 = a3;

cout << "a1[2]: " << a1[2] << " at " << &a1[2] << endl;
cout << "a2[2]: " << a2[2] << " at " << &a2[2] << endl;
cout << "a3[2]: " << a3[2] << " at " << &a3[2] << endl;
cout << "a4[2]: " << a4[2] << " at " << &a4[2] << endl;

a1[-2] = 20.2;
cout << "a1[-2]: " << a1[-2] << " at " << &a1[-2] << endl;
cout << "a3[2]: " << a3[2] << " at " << &a3[2] << endl;
cout << "a4[2]: " << a4[2] << " at " << &a4[2] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

the result is

```
a1[2]: 3.6 at 0x7fff5fbff7f0
a2[2]: 0.142857 at 0x100105520
a3[2]: 1.62 at 0x7fff5fbff648
a4[2]: 1.62 at 0x7fff5fbff628
a1[-2]: 20.2 at 0x7fff5fbff7d0
a3[2]: 1.62 at 0x7fff5fbff648
a4[2]: 1.62 at 0x7fff5fbff628
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Environment: mac os , xcode 7.1.1

I puzzle with the class array: why address of a4 is different from a3 , thus a4 equal to a3 (also i think a4 point to a3).

Assume: 
1.c++ reload operator "=", when class array appear, it will alloc memory to array and assign value by for-loop(maybe by other way).
2.actually, i can't really distinguish pointer from class.

Comment: `a4` and `a3` are two distinct, independent variables, that simply happen to hold the same values. When you write `int x = 42; int y = 42;`, you don't end up with `x` and `y` magically glued together into a single object just because they happen to hold the same value at the moment. Nothing changes if instead of `int y = 42;` you write `int y = x;` Similarly, `a4 = a3;` just makes `a4` hold the same value as `a3` - it doesn't magically make `a4` and `a3` the same object.

Comment: Why not [read the documentation for `std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik some languages do behave that way (with Array classes, not ints), so people coming here from C# or Java might have that misconception

Answer (score 0):

`array<>` is actually a struct, and the whole point of it is to support some functionality not provided in normal built in one ([]). for example, one of these functionalities is the assignment.

```
int a[4];   
int b[5];  
a=b //Error    

array<int,4> a;  
array<int,4> b;
a=b // valid
```

another functionality is accessing the size, when you pass an array of built in `type[]` to a function you have to pass the size along with it, but with `array<>` type you can get the size by calling .size()
Now a pointer is a data type that holds a value which is an address in the memory. so when you say `int a[4]`, then try to print `cout<<a;` you will get and address value. but if you print `a[0]` then the compiler understand as (get the value of the pointer `a`, go to that address and get the value stored there) Having said that, to make the first assignment I wrote up valid you can do this,

```
int a[4];   
int* b; //now b is a pointer that points to an integer   
b= a; // valid
```

now to print first element in `a` you simply access it by calling `a[0]` but to do that with the pointer `b`, you use `*b` which the `*` operator before a pointer means that get the value stored in that address. Lets get a bit tricky and try to get `a[1]` using  `b`.  Since Integers are 4 bytes, then the next element will be 4 times ahead of first one (memory addresses byte oriented), so `a[1]` is equal to `*(b+4)` and so on.
if you use the new keyword then you will get the behaviour you are expecting I think

```
int* a = new int[3]{1,2,3};   
int* b;   
b= a;   
cout << &a[2] << "  " << &b[2]; //output will be same value
```

reason is that when you use new key word memory is allocated in the heap and it will not be deallocated unless you do it yourself even though you get out of the scope the variable is defined in, so assigning values just links them to each other, not copy the whole value itself (make sense to optimise performance otherwise you will run out of memory sooner than you imagine). I hope you got something from this answer :). read documentation for more info.

Answer (score -3):

When you assign an array object you are assigning a new address to variable a3 and a4 separately but you are assigning the same value to both addresses . Hence they have the same value but different addresses

Comment: `you are assigning a new address to variable` With all due respect, that's just nonsense. `&a4` remains the same before and after the assignment, as so does `&a3`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  so actually the class array<type, n_element> will be assign address once you declaration. And the operator reload "=" when array<type, n_element> appear